# Why IEEE 754 Single Precision floating point numbers cannot have exponent -127?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, exponent

I read that for IEEE 754 Single Precision floating point numbers, the exponents can go from -126 to 127. Why can't -127 be an exponent? As 127 is the bias, -127+127 = 0, which can be represented as eight 0s. So is there any other reason not to allow the exponent to be all 0s?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding

Comment: An exponent field of 0 is reserved for denormals.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks, I overlooked that page, I couldn't find the information as I visited the Wikipedia page about IEEE 754.

Comment: Does the Wikipedia page answer your question adequately, or are you asking why the exponent encoding 0 is used for subnormal values rather than being used for normal values with an exponent of −127?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually the former, but the latter is actually a very interesting point. I suppose using the exponent encoding 0 is a convention? Surely, I expect any system always uses either the max or min exponent encoding for such special purposes, otherwise there can be big trouble in processing and doing calculations.

Comment: @GreenPenguin: The maximum exponent is used for another special purpose (infinity and NaN), but the encoding is not as important as the fact that there are subnormals. Briefly, some behaviors are nicer if there are subnormals—if the exponent clamps at a lower bound and then the significands get smaller without decreasing the exponent anymore. Notably, if 0 encoded a normal exponent, you could have representable `x` and `y` such `x` != `y` but `x-y` had to be zero because the mathematical difference is too small. So code to avoid dividing by zero would break, as in `if x != y then q = p/(x-y)`.